# How do I obtain the eigenvalues of a huge matrix (size: 2x10^5)

Tags: perl, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of size 200000 X 200000 .I need to find the eigen values for this .I was using matlab till now but as the size of the matrix is unhandleable by matlab i have shifted to perl and now even perl is unable to handle this huge matrix it is saying out of memory.I would like to know if i can find out the eigen values of this matrix using some other programming language which can handle such huge data. The elements are not zeros mostly so no option of going for sparse matrix. Please help me in solving this.

Comment: In double precision just storing the dense 200000x200000 matrix will be ~300GB of memory. The problem is most likely not the programming language that you use, but the RAM and swap space of the computer you are using.

Comment: Do you know the nature of your matrix? If it's a random Gaussian matrix (or if you can approximate your data to be so), there are several analytical results I could provide that will tell you the distribution of the eigenvalues (asymptotically). For a matrix of this size, you almost _cannot_ go wrong if you use the asymptotic results, and I'd dare to wager that a 200000 point sample from that distribution will be pretty damn near the actual eigenvalues. If this is not the case, do you know if your requirements are small? Like for e.g., do you need just the largest eigenvalue or all?

Comment: Further along yoda's line of thought: if you're doing stats work (which includes a lot of what is called data mining and machine learning), do you really need to work with the full data set or would a smaller (~1e4) sample be sufficient? You might consider providing some details about the problem that is behind this matrix, there might be better ways of getting what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may still have luck with MATLAB. Take a look into their [distributed computing toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/supported/parallel.html). You'd need some kind of parallel environment, a computing cluster.

If you don't have a computational cluster, you might look into distributed eigenvalue/vector calculation methods that could be employed on [Amazon EC2 or similar](http://www.princeton.edu/~aspremon/MCeigs.pdf).

There is also a discussion of parallel eigenvalue calculation methods [here](http://www.cse.scitech.ac.uk/arc/diags.shtml), which may direct you to better libraries and programming approaches than Perl.